# Test stage failed in GitLab CI for .NET Core projects

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, gitlab, nunit

I'm facing trouble with my GitLab CI. The expected workflow for my Test stage is :

- fetching changes
- checking out
- downloading artifacts
- run dotnet test
- uploading artifacts

The current workflow is :

- fetching changes
- checking out (removing all bin/obj folder)
- uploading artifacts -> this line failed due to inexistance of my test-results.xml file

My solution looks like this:
-- yml file
-- MyApp
-- MyApp.Tests

The version of my gitlab-runner is 12.4.1 and I'm using the shell executor on Windows environment.

Please find below my yml file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
variables:
  EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER: 'Oncolin.UI.Desktop\bin\Release'
  # the folder inside the deploy folder 
  DEPLOY_FOLDER_APP: 'Oncolin.UI.Desktop\Builds'
  CONFIGURATION: 'release'

 #NUGET_PATH: 'C:\NuGet\nuget.exe'
 #MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
 #MSTEST_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe'
 NUNIT_PATH: '.\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe'

 SOLUTION: 'Oncolin.sln'

stages:
 - build
 - test

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
   - windows
script:
  - '& nuget restore' # restore Nuget dependencies
  - '& dotnet restore'
  - '& SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:Oncolin /d:sonar.host.url=https://docker:10500 '
  - '& dotnet build -c release'
  - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" "$env:SOLUTION" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release' # build the project
  - '& SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end'
artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 week # save gitlab server space, we copy the files we need to deploy folder later on
  paths:
    - '$env:EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER\*' # saving exe to copy to deploy folder
    - 'RNC.RULES.QUALITY.TESTS\*' # saving entire Test project so NUnit can run tests 
    - 'RNC.MODEL.TNM.TESTS\*' # saving entire Test project so NUnit can run tests 
    - 'Oncolin.Model.Tests\*' # saving entire Test project so NUnit can run tests 
  
test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - windows
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - '& dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=$CI_PROJECT_DIR\artifacts\{assembly}-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"' 
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week # save gitlab server space, we copy the files we need to deploy folder later on
    when: always
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR\artifacts\*test-result.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - $CI_PROJECT_DIR\artifacts\*test-result.xml
  dependencies:
    - build
```

Can someone explain to me why the downloading and dotnet test steps are skipped ? I hope I gave enough informations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from the sonar scanner. Even if I used the .Net Core sonar scanner, I had the same issue during my test stage.
I don't know why and I have already lost too many time to investigate on that.

I resolved it by creating a new stage specificly to run the sonar and ran it after the test stage.